# Google Analytics Query Explorer OR AND logic

Tags: google, analytics, api, reporting

I use the following link to create queries for the Core Reporting API of Google Analytics:https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Now I want to use a filter that filters out two types of traffic:
1. filter out a specific type of medium
2. filter out a speciic type of medium in combination with a type of source.

Now I'm using the following filter expression:
ga:medium==organic,ga:medium==cpc;ga:source==google

But the first medium filter also uses the source filter.
So I actually want to exclude the source filter from the first medium filter.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

AND and OR are equivalent so it's impossible in that way. More info and examples, you'll find there: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#OR

But... there is a simple solution. Use ga:sourceMedium to filter out combined specific type of medium with a source. E.g.
filter expression: 
`ga:sourceMedium==google / cpc,ga:medium==organic`